# Access VBA: select column by order index

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my subform, I would like to change the width of a column identified by the order. In this case, I am trying to resize the second column.

```
Me.[Table subform].Form.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = "1500"
```

The syntax is not correct and I am sure that the wrong segment is `Columns(2)`. How to manage it?

Comment: Try using a number, like: `=1500`.

Comment: @Gustav the issue is not the value. the code works if I put the name of the column instead of Column(2). But I need to use the index of the column, so I have to find the right syntax to change the width of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to loop the controls of the subform - something like this (aircode):

```
For Each Control In Me.[Table subform].Form.Controls
    If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        If Control.ColumnOrder = 2 Then
            ' Control/column located.
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not Control Is Nothing Then
    Control.ColumnWidth = 1500
End If
```